# XmlDocument availability

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I'm trying to deal with xml in a uwp app, I have added reference and usings:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

But a `private XmlDocument doc;` throws the compiler error:

> Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I check the doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) it clearly says it is available in uwp since windows 10:

```
Version Information

Universal Windows Platform 
Available since 10
.NET Framework 
Available since 1.1
```

This type is also in .net core [too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.xml.xmldocument).

What should I do to use this type in the app?

Comment: I've been tried in Win7, It is working but don't know in win10

Comment: Did you create a uwp project or a windows project?

Comment: Don't understand uwp.. can you explain? Universal Windows Project? How to create it? could you tell me

Comment: My problem is specific to uwp, aka Universal windows platform, it uses a somewhat different subset of .net api, you can check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx.

Comment: Thanks this is new to me.. if you can guide me then thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've known, [System.Xml.XmlDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used in UWP apps. However, to use this class in UWP, we need to take care of [Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/).

If you use the **5.1.0 Version** of this package, then there should be no error.

But if you are using the latest stable **5.2.2 version** of this package, you will get the **`Compiler Error CS0246`** as you've mentioned.

To solve this issue, you can add [System.Xml.XmlDocument Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/4.0.1) (4.0.1 version) into your project. The ***project.json*** file might like the following.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
    "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": { }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": { },
    "win10-arm-aot": { },
    "win10-x86": { },
    "win10-x86-aot": { },
    "win10-x64": { },
    "win10-x64-aot": { }
  }
}
```

After adding the reference, you can rebuild your project, the compiler error should now disappear.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I wonder why adding reference through Reference manager does not work? There is exactly System.Xml.XmlDocument assembly in there: http://i.imgur.com/ao9z9ZP.png

Comment: @fluter The package used in UWP is a NuGet package. To add reference, we need to use **"Manage NuGet Packages"**.